# Can't focus to main app after switching to another workspace

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, 23.10, workspace-switcher, ubuntu-budgie

I just tried Ubuntu Budgie 23.10, after switching to another workspace with
shortcuts like <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>LEFT</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>RIGHT</kbd> the focus isn’t on the main app.
To focus on the app I have to first click on it which is not good for me.

How to change that?

Comment: Maybe use `Alt + Tab`?

Comment: I think, instead of "can't focus", you mean that "the focus _does not get automatically restored_ after switching back and forth between workspaces (which would be a senseful feature to expect, and it works like that in other distros)".